# How to I solve this sass interpolation issue

Tags: css, angular, sass

WARNING: You probably don't mean to use the color value white in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as white, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings or map keys (for example, "white").
If you really want to use the color value here, use '"" + $colorName'.

```
   ╷
93 │       .text-#{$colorName}-#{$shade} {
   │               ^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    src\assets\styles\scss\_palette.scss 93:15  @import
    stdin 44:9
```

I tried something like this as recommended,

```
.text-#{'"" + $colorName'}-#{$shade} {
```

But just adding the quotes didn't work.
I am using angular cli.

Comment: Have you tried `.text-#{"" + $colorName}-#{$shade} {`?

Answer (score 46):

Recently upgraded to the **Angular9** and was facing the same issue. In my case updting this

```
.#{$colorName}#{$hue}-bg {
        background-color: $color !important;
}
```

to

```
.#{"" + $colorName}#{$hue}-bg {
        background-color: $color !important;
}
```

worked.

Comment: That's also work for me while update angular version 10 to 11.

Answer (score 14):

Found this post in a GitHub issue (https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/2409#issuecomment-311932161).
The underlying issue are unquoted map keys.

(Credits to [@xzyfer](https://github.com/xzyfer).)

```
$testMap: (
-    white: (color: white) // white is a Color object
+    "white": (color: white) // "white" is a String object
);

@each $key in map-keys($testMap) {
    .test-btn-#{$key} {
        $colors: map_get($testMap, $key);

        color: map-get($colors, color);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer and root of the problem.  I had a css file with variables where I remapped the colors and wasn't quoting the map keys (because you didn't do that before some update).  But if you look at the bootstrap css or online (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color/), you can see that they are quoting their map keys as well.

Answer (score 7):

this should dispose the warning:

```
#{'.text-' + $colorName + '-' + $shade}
```