# How to remove SCSS warnings while building Angular app

Tags: angular, sass, node-sass

I removed **node-sass** package, which is no longer needed in the Angular application.
But now I get warnings, which looks like these, during the build:

```
WARNING: You probably don't mean to use the color value white in interpolation here.   
It may end up represented as white, which will likely produce invalid CSS.             
Always quote color names when using them as strings or map keys (for example, "white").
If you really want to use the color value here, use '"" + $name'.                      
                                                                                       
   ╷                                                                                   
37 │   .mg-#{$name}-p {                                                                
   │         ^^^^^                                                                     
   ╵                                                                                   
    src\assets\scss\_colors.scss 37:9  @import                                         
    src\assets\scss\app.scss 7:9       @import                                         
    src\styles.scss 8:9                root stylesheet
```

**I don't intend to fix these problems**, is there a way to just disable warnings?

Comment: can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455245/how-to-i-solve-this-sass-interpolation-issue

Comment: @ManuJanardhanan That looks more ugly than before fixing, I'de prefer to disable all warnings at once...